# Remove a users permission from folder

Tags: powershell

I created this script that will create a folder for each user that has a title of Customer Service Representative on a UNC path.There is a users group that is inherited from the parent. How can I remove that users group?

```
$names = (Get-ADUser -Filter 'Title -eq "Customer Service Representative"').name
foreach ($name in $names)
{
New-Item -ItemType "directory" -Path "\\unc\$name" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$path = "\\unc\$name" #Replace with whatever file you want to do this to.
$user = "domain\group" #User account to grant permisions too.
$Rights = "Full" #"Read, ReadAndExecute, ListDirectory" #Comma seperated list.
$InheritSettings = "Containerinherit, ObjectInherit" #Controls how permissions are inherited by 
children
$PropogationSettings = "None" #Usually set to none but can setup rules that only apply to children.
$RuleType = "Allow" #Allow or Deny.
$acl = Get-Acl $path
$perm = $user, $Rights, $InheritSettings, $PropogationSettings, $RuleType
$rule = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList $perm
$acl.SetAccessRule($rule)
$acl | Set-Acl -Path $path
}
```

Comment: Did you search for an answer? 3rd link led me to https://serverfault.com/a/841024/88709 which gives you the answer, I think.

Comment: I did but it doesnt make sense how to apply it to my script

Comment: Also remove-ntfsaccess is not a cmdlet

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're comfortable with an add-on, but you may want to check out this [NTFS PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/1abd77a5-9c0b-4a2b-acef-90dbb2b84e85) module:

I've been using it for years.  It's quite capable, and very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

From an admin console of PowerShell
`install-package ntfssecurity`

Before your closing `{` add the line
`Remove-NTFSAccess -AccessRights FullControl -Account DOMAIN\Group -Path $path -AccessType Deny -AppliesTo ThisFolderSubfoldersAndFiles`

At least, that's what I'm guessing would be appropriate?  Haven't studied your code that deeply to know what you're doing exactly.  I'd probably drop it in right after folder creation, but that doesn't appear to happen in here?